# Merging list of python dictionaries by column value

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, data-science

I have data that is a list of python dictionaries, each representing a row in the data, and want to combine several of these into one dictionary.

I need to combine them by a common value in a single column, note the dictionaries to merge may or may not contain similar columns and values should be concatenated, not clobbered.

Here is an example (combining dicts by value in column 'a'):

```
data = [{ 'a':0, 'b':10, 'c':20 }
{ 'a':2, 'd':30, 'e':40 }
{ 'a':0, 'b':50, 'c':60 }
{ 'a':1, 'd':70, 'c':80 }
{ 'a':1, 'b':90, 'e':100 }]
```

Desired output is:

```
new_data = [{ 'a':0, 'b':[10,50], 'c':[20,60] }
{ 'a':1, 'd':[70], 'c':[80], 'b':[90], 'e':[100] }
{ 'a':2, 'd':[30], 'e':[40] }]
```

I have a simple function that can accomplish this, but need a faster method (Data has approx 1,000,000 rows and 20 columns). My method of finding the dictionaries I want to merge is very expensive.

Here is where I have an issue with computation time:

```
unique_idx, locations = [], {}
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        _id = row['a']
        if _id not in unique_idx:
            unique_idx.append(_id)
            locations[_id] = [i]
        else:
            locations[_id].append(i)

grouped_data = [data[loc] for loc in locations.values()]
```

I need a faster method to collect dictionaries that contain the same value in one column. Ideally I want a quick method with plain python, but if this can be done simply with a pandas DataFrame that is good as well.

Comment: Instead of working with dictionaries, if you do data science, pandas is usually a good package. It combines numpy and database-like processing of data.

Comment: Yes, list or tuple there is what I was going for, made edit to question

Comment: Does order matter? Should the output use the order of first appearance of values for `a` or doesn't that matter?

Comment: Also, if these are rows from a database, why not have the *database* do the grouping?

Comment: AFAI can tell, you could go from quadratic to linear time complexity simply by turning `unique_idx` into a `set`: `unique_idx, locations = set(), {}` and `unique_idx.add(_id)`

Comment: The order does not matter, the data is from a csv with multiple rows containing the same ID number, I am trying to efficiently aggregate these rows.